# Using a boolean to check if the number inside the string is a natural

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i'm trying to make a function to check if the numbers inside a string is natural.

So my code is like this

```
def natural(x):
     while True:
          return x.isdigit() and 0 <= int(x) <= 9
```

I want my outputs to be like this

```
natural('05')
True

natural('asasassaas')
False

natural('243,432,355')
False
```

My question is how would i account for exponentially large numbers?

Comment: What is an exponential number?

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are just looking for the isdigit function - it works for all of the examples that you have listed here, and, being written in c, is almost certainly faster than a pure python solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for you to do the additional check here:

```
and 0 <= int(x) <= 9
```

The `isdigit` method does this for you already. You pretty much want to stick with `isdigit`

Furthermore, a simplification can be made with the code where you can just stick to using `isdigit` like so:

```
def natural(x):
    return x.isdigit()
```

Thanks to @SteveJessop for the discussion on this.

Comment: Same comment as for Simeon's answer: this is the same as `x.isdigit()` except on the corner case of empty strings.

Comment: @SteveJessop I didn't mention it explicitly, might have been good to mention that. I updated my answer to indicate this. Thoughts?

Comment: I think you've made the answer actually wrong now, before you were merely writing too much code for the result you produce. `isdigit()` does *not* do the 0 to 9 test for you. `'10'.isdigit()` is True in Python. Although the questioner's code is so confused, it's possible they think they're doing a test on each character of the string in turn...

Comment: I fail to see why you would not want to match '10' as a digit?

Comment: It's not a matter of wanting anything. My first point is that your proposed code `def natural(x): return all(i.isdigit() for i in x)` would, aside from the result when passing it the empty string, be better written as `def natural(x): return x.isdigit()`. My second point is that the statement "The isdigit method does this for you already" appears to me to be wrong, since there are plenty of strings `x` for which `x.isdigit()` is true and `0 <= int(x) <= 9` is false. That is to say, `isdigit()` *does not* do the check you say it does.

Comment: Anyway, since the intent of the code in the question is so unclear (what is the loop for? what is the code the questioner is actually running? - not this code since `While` is a typo!), as well as what "exponentially large numbers" means, I'm not sure a correct answer is really possible at this point...

Comment: @SteveJessop I hope you didn't take any of my comments as aggressive. I appreciated the discussion. I actually see what you mean with your code sample. I don't know why I didn't see it before, it is very obvious that simply checking isdigit() is the best approach. I am updating my answer for this.

Comment: no, didn't read you as aggressive, although apologies if I've come on rather too strong in response, in trying to say the same thing again in different words :-)

Comment: Cheers @SteveJessop :)

Comment: p.s. @SteveJessop I updated the answer once again concluding what we discussed. I *think* it should be OK now :)

Answer (score -1):

You can loop over all characters in the provided string:

```
def natural(x):
    for c in x:
        if not c.isdigit():
            return False
    return True
```

This will stop once it encounters the first character that is not a digit.

Comment: That's the same as `x.isdigit()`, except on empty strings where this returns `True` but `''.isdigit()` is `False`.

Comment: I.e., `def natural(x): return not x or x.isdigit()`